# accessing matlab arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array that contains pixel values of images. I want to store them in a 1D array. How can I do it? And how can I access the individual elements in the 2D array through the 1D array?

Answer (score 0):

First, it might help to know a little bit about your intended goal. However, if we assume your array is called `Img`, you can always use the `reshape()` function to reshape the image into a new array with shape `numel(Img)` by `1`:

```
 new_Img = reshape(Img, numel(Img), 1);
```

According to the documentation, this stores the entries column-wise, meaning that it first gets all of the elements of column 1, then column 2, and so on. So if you wanted to get back entry `(i,j)` from the original two-dimensional array `Img`, you would index into `new_Img` like this (letting `M` be the number of rows in the matrix):

```
 linear_indx = (j-1)*M+i;
 new_Img(linear_indx) == Img(i,j);
```

Note that a lot of other libraries expect things to be ordered by rows, and so you could first transpose your image and then reshape, and adjust the linear index accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For an array P with dimensions (m,n) the statement

```
reshape(P,[],1)
```

will return an (m*n) column vector; swap the order of the last 2 arguments to return a row vector.  Be careful that your array of pixels is (m,n), if you have RGB triples, for example, your array might be (m,n,3), in which case you have to be a bit cleverer with reshape, but the principle remains the same.

You do not need to do anything to use a single index into a 2D array.  For example, the reference

```
P(i)
```

will return the i-th element of the array counting the elements in the order `(1,1), (2,1), (3,1) ...` that is, Matlab stores arrays in column-major order

Comment: Linear indexing is not limited to 2D arrays; all MATLAB arrays are actually linear data structures. [Here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86528.html#f1-86846) is some documentation explaining things and giving the `sub2ind` formula for N-D arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

```
B = A(:);
```

To access `B` using the same indices as in `A`:

```
B(sub2ind(size(A),i,j));
```

And a full example:

```
% init
A = randn(10,5);
A(7,5)
>>> -0.1904

% 2-d -> 1-d
B = A(:);

% access
B(sub2ind(size(A),7,5))
>>> -0.1904
```